# Unable to show webservice response in html using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, spring, web-services

I am fetching a list of users from angular js by making a call to spring rest webservice . I am receiving a response in my service but not able to print the same in html file. There is no error on console.

services.js

```
    fetchUsersDetails:function(){
        var deferred=$q.defer();
        var url="http://localhost:8081/HCP_Android_Demo/fetchUsers";
        return $http.post(url).success(function(response){
            deferred.resolve(response);
        }).error(function(response){
            alert("The error response is"+response);            
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

controller.js

```
function fetchUsers(){
    UserService.fetchUsersDetails().then(function(responseData){
        $scope.userData = responseData.data.usersList;
        $scope.result = responseData.data.Result;
        alert("users list is"+$scope.userData);//prints [Object object]
        alert("result is"+$scope.result);//prints ok
    });
};
```

Controller.java

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/fetchUsers",method={RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})
@ResponseBody
public String fetchUsers()throws JSONException{
    System.out.println("Inside fetchUsers");
    List<User> userList=userService.fetchUsers();
    ArrayList<JSONObject> arrayList=new ArrayList<JSONObject> ();
    try{
        for(User user:userList){
            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("name", user.getUsername());
            jsonObject.put("address", user.getAddress());
            jsonObject.put("email",user.getEmail());
            arrayList.add(jsonObject);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception exception){
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONObject usersList=new JSONObject();
    usersList.put("Result", "OK");
    usersList.accumulate("usersList", arrayList);
    /*return callBackFunction +"(" + jsonObject.toString() + ")";   */  
    return  usersList.toString() ;

}
```

Login.jsp

```
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="UserController as ctrl">
    <div>
    <span class="tableLabel">List Of users</span>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="users in ctrl.userData ">
                <td><span>{{users.username}}</span></td>
                <td><span>{{users.address}}</span></td>
                <td><span>{{usesr.email}}</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

json

```
  {"usersList":[{"address":"sssssssss","name":"disha","email":"ssss"},{"address":"xxxx","name":"xxx","email":"xxx"},{"address":"jain.xyz92@gmail.com","name":"disha","email":"xxx"}],"Result":"OK"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using controller as syntax witch do you create a new instance and you can access to properties you have bound to controller  directly from the controller instance. If you want to use controller as syntax then you bind your function or object to the controller instead $scope. You could do this

```
var vm = this.

vm.yourData = resultFromBeckend ;
```

and in view

```
ng-controller="Ctrl as ctrl"
{{ctrl.yourData}}
```

In your case change this line.
From

```
 $scope.userData = responseData.data.usersList;
```

To

```
 vm.userData = responseData.data.usersList;
```

Your `userData` is not on the controller it's on the `$scope`.
It's also best practice to bind your object to the controller and use controller as syntax. 
Angular Best Practice from JhonPapa

Comment: what is the difference from the post i have posted above you?

Comment: Actually i am updating once i posted the answer

Comment: I can see that but I saw it after I have posted mine. If you had explained in the first hand I would never put the same answer it would be just stupid.

Comment: Thanx both of you .Actually I thought controllerAs and scope can be used simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Controller as syntax` you have to change the controller  where the variables can be bind directly to the view.

**JS:**

```
app.controller("UserController", ["$http",
    function( $http) {
             var vm =this;
             $http.get('test.json').then(function (response){
              vm.userData = response.data.usersList ;
        });

}]);
```

Working [`Plunker`](https://plnkr.co/edit/pshPiq6AerJDPDFRcWAn?p=preview)

Change your view like below  in order to access your data directly since you are using $scope variable,

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="UserController">
    <div>
    <span class="tableLabel">List Of users</span>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="users in userData ">
                <td><span>{{users.username}}</span></td>
                <td><span>{{users.address}}</span></td>
                <td><span>{{usesr.email}}</span></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

Working [`Plunker`](https://plnkr.co/edit/pshPiq6AerJDPDFRcWAn?p=preview)